# How to Use Keyboard service as an app? 

Tags: android

I know that keyboard is a service  but i want to show it like an app on my desktop just like any other app  i'm using sample softkeyboard code  as a reference

Any Idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but perhaps this will help. You want to show the 'keyboard like an app' on your desktop? Does this mean that you want an icon to click on that opens the soft keyboard? If so, perhaps the following code may be of use to you. This will simply display the soft keyboard.

```
InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMgr.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
```

More info on this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340137/soft-keyboard-wont-appear/5340162#5340162).

Comment: @Shd, it depends on when you want to display the soft keyboard. If you have an event or method that should trigger the display of the keyboard, try pasting it there. However, note that the variable mContext is a reference to the current application context. Just make sure you have access to the context before using that code.

I might be able to give you a clearer answer if I understood what it is you would like to do with this soft keyboard.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to enable the keyboard on the phones keyboard settings after installing your apk.

- Settings > Language and Keyboard
- Select your keyboard (maybe un-check the default Android keyboard as well)

see [here](http://code.google.com/p/softkeyboard/wiki/HowTo) for guide!